# Control a 110v AC motor with a 5v digitally controlled potentiometer

Tags: arduino, ac, control

I have a manual variable resistor(turn the knob) connected between 110v and an ac motor that pumps air to make bubbles in my portable hot tub. I have had it for about a year and it works fine to adjust the speed of the motor to vary the amount of bubbles. I however am wanting to have this controlled digitally so that I can use an arduino to vary it based upon other sensor values. Is there a simple 5v digitally controlled device that allows for 110v AC control. I know this is easy with a 5v relay, but I am confused if there is a simple a solution to what I am looking to do.

Comment: use a servo to turn the knob

Comment: Use a servo to turn the knob is likely a simple as you are going to get. You can buy a voltage control box that replaces everything except the motor, but it is likely to cost more and may be difficult to properly select for the motor.

Comment: Would something like this be a possibility

Comment: https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html

Comment: Show your current circuit with all parts detailed enough to find them on the web.